# Unable to change global variables from function

Tags: python, variables, global, local

I'm trying to implement some of the things I've learned so far into a simple text game, but I'm having trouble trying to change a global variable in one function so that it stays changed for another.

```
keynumb = 0
```

That's the global variable. I'm trying to change it to 1 inside a function and then calling it in another (`if 1 open the door, if 0 don't`) etc..

Been trying for about an hour until my brain just died on me, hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

I added asterisks where the lines are in the code.

Cheers.

```
from sys import exit

keynumb = 0


def start():
    print "You are in a room with two doors in front of you. One on the left, and one on the right."
    while True:
        door_choice = raw_input("Do you take the left or right door? Your choice: ")
        if "left" in door_choice or "Left" in door_choice:
            dark_room()
        elif "right" in door_choice:
            monster_room()
        else:
            print "I don't understand."

def dark_room():
    print "You find yourself in a dark room, unable to see anything."
    while True:
        dr_choice = raw_input("What do you do?")
        if "light" and "switch" in dr_choice or "turn" and "light" in dr_choice:
            print "You've turn on the light and the room is illuminated."
            print "On the floor is a small silver key."
            dr_choice_light = raw_input("What do you do?")
            if "pick" in dr_choice_light:
                print "You pick up the key and exit back the way you came."
                keynumber()   *************
                start()
            elif "nothing" in dr_choice_light:
                print "You do nothing. Nothing happens."
            elif "back" in dr_choice_light or "exit" in dr_choice_light:
                start()     
        else:
            print "That didn't do anything."        


def monster_room():
    print "It seems this door is locked and requires a key."
    while True:
        mons = raw_input("What do you do?")
        if "key" in mons and keynumb == 0:   **************
            print "You don't have a key, dummy. Might as well turn back.."
        elif "key" in mons and keynumb == 1:
            print "You open it using the small silver key."
            print "You enter the room and a huge monster looks up from his iPhone. \"You want to get past me?\" he says. Well, if you know what 4 + 4 is then I'll let you pass." 
            answer = raw_input("What is 4+4?")
            if answer == "8":
                print "\"Well done!\" says the monster. He smiles as you pass to the door behind him."
            else: 
                print "Stupid. You die."
                exit
        elif "back" in mons:
            print "You turn back."
            start()     
        else:
            print "I don't understand."

def keynumber():   **********
    global keynumb += 1
    return keynumb


start()
```

Comment: Quiz: What is wrong with this line: `if "light" and "switch" in dr_choice or "turn" and "light" in dr_choice:` ?

Comment: Should 'in dr_choice' come after light and turn also, otherwise I'm just asking 'if "light'"? (which, big guess here..  is like a boolean? Returns True/False if it's just an if statement?)

Comment: @isherwood Or, to add to that ^ (too late to edit).. My other guess is, Is that whole way of doing it, even the revised way, not making sense because too many and/or bits? Is there a way, maybe to use a comma to separate two strings, so it could be something like:  if "light", "switch" in Dr_choice or "turn", "light" in Dr_choice....?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong in `keynumber`

You want something like

```
def keynumber():
    global keynumb
    keynumb += 1
```

I left out the return statement since you don't seem to be using it there anyway

Comment: Ah brilliant, cheers, works perfectly. Think I was way overcomplicating it.

Comment: `exit` is a function. Call it as `exit()` in your monster room function when he dies